# Quartz Scheduler execute job only if it is not already running

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

In my java web application I am using Quartz CronTrigger Bean to schedule the execution of a job. In my configuration xml file I want to trigger the job every 10 minutes:

```
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="processToExecuteJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/10 * * * ?" />
</bean>
```

How can I check if the job is already running, and in tat case I do not need to run it again.
I want to ensure that only one instance of the job can be running at certain time.

Comment: Can't your job just check whether an instance already exists and exit if it does?

Comment: Yes it can... Thank you :) I thought that there is a solution offered by org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean it self.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes the simple solutions are the best. ;)

Comment: Probably, i didn't understand the question. But, there is @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation in Quartz: _"An annotation that marks a Job class as one that must not have multiple instances executed concurrently (where instance is based-upon a JobDetail definition - or in other words based upon a JobKey)"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem in an old project I worked on. I think an elegant solution in this case always the Singleton pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern